# How to get value of ngx-Summernote runtime

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, summernote

I am now using ngx-Summernote in Ionic 5 + Angular project.

Is there anyway to get value as ngModel?
I tried

```
<div [ngxSummernote]="config" [ngxSummernoteView]="content"></div>
```

The problem is, when i set "HELLO" to the content at the construct, then it was working.
But when i tried to update content on runtime, it was not update summernote.

I tried to find examples but so far no luck.
Hope for your kind help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the summernoteModel as:

```
<div
    [ngxSummernote]="config"
    [(summernoteModel)]="htmlOutput">
```

Where htmlOutput is a string that updates every time when you change anything in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get it, I tried in Ionic 5 + Angular project. and it worked for me

```xml
<input [ngxSummernote] type="text" class="form-control" 
    formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="cName" placeholder="Enter Name">
```